# Interpolation of a function from numerical data and getting plots

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, fitting, plot-themes

I need to plot between two functions $f(h)$ and $g(h)$. I have the numerical data of $f$ w.r.t. $h$. So I just tried to get the expression of the function using the codes f[x_]=Fit[data,{1,x,x^2},x] but I am not getting the desirable plot. Is there any other way to get the plot? Kindly let me know.

Comment: `ListLinePlot[fdata]`

Comment: I want the plot between f(h) and g(h).

Comment: `ListLinePlot[{fdata, gdata}]`?

Comment: I think it's unclear what you mean by "plotting between two functions". Can you explain what you want, maybe with a sketch? Also please share the numerical data you have, and the code you have tried so far, as formatted text.

Comment: `ListLinePlot[{fdata, gdata}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean something like this...

```
f[x_] := Sin[x];
g[x_] := Log[x];
Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, .5, 3}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}]
```

**EDIT**

To answer the question about getting a function from data, you probably want Interpolation. Let's make up some data and then forget where it came from:

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

I've got a bunch of sample points and want a continuous function. Let's try Interpolation:

```
theFunc = Interpolation[data]
```

And again, you can plot as above:

```
Plot[{theFunc[x], g[x]}, {x, .5, 3}, Filling -> {2}]
```

Comment: I don't know the exact expression of $f[h]$ but  I have the numerical data. so how can I get it? I used Fit[f,{1,h,h^2},h] but didn't get desirable result.

Comment: Updated to answer. Maybe you can edit your question to clarify for future readers. As it stands, I can't really tell if your question is "how to interpolate?" or "how to plot?". Based on the title "Plotting between two functions", I thought it was the plotting that was your main challenge.

Comment: Thank you, but still, I am not getting the desirable plot. I want to use ListLinePlot, so I can see the behavior of $g(x)$ w r.t the $f(x)$.

Comment: Ah. I misunderstood "between".

Answer (score 1):

- We `Interpolation` the two data `dataF` and `dataG`, then get the parametric form of the curve `{F[t],G[t]}`.

```
Clear[dataF, dataG, F, G];
dataF = Table[Cos[h], {h, 0, π, .5}];
dataG = Table[Sin[h], {h, 0, π, .5}];
{F, G} = Interpolation /@ {dataF, dataG};
Plot[{F@h, G@h}, {h, 1, Length@dataF}]
ParametricPlot[{F@h, G@h}, {h, 1, Length@dataF}, 
 Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5], Red, 
   Point@Transpose@{dataF, dataG}}]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the continuous case (probably using Interpolation), you could use ParametricPlot:

```
f = Sin; g = Cos;(* just examples since I don't know your actual f and g *)
ParametricPlot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -1, 3}]
```

In the discrete case, you could use ListLinePlot after transposing the data:

```
fdata = Array[Sin, 7, {-1, 3}];
gdata = Array[Cos, 7, {-1, 3}];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{fdata, gdata}]]
```